# why "a" is bigger than "A" in python?

Tags: python

```
print(4 > 5)
```

output is False
this is very easy to understand using basic math

```
print("a" > "A")
```

output is True

how does python compare a and A ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python string comparison is performed using the characters in both strings. The characters in both strings are compared one by one. When different characters are found then their Unicode value is compared. The character with lower Unicode value is considered to be smaller.

The `Unicode` value of `'A'` is `65`, whereas the for `'a'` it is `97`.

The `ord()` function returns the `Unicode` value of a character.

```
ord('A')  # returns 65
ord('a')  # returns 97
ord('AA')  # ERROR: ord() expects a string of length 1.
```

Comment: Note that you can get with unicode value with the `ord` functions.

Comment: Great addition! Added to include, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"a" ascii is 97 --> `ord("a")`

"A" ascii is 65 --> `ord("A")`

Hence:

```
print("a" > "A") --> True
```